# fill NA with most common value for last N columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe.
After concatenating columns I have lots of NA (because dataframes not of the same length).

For the last N columns, I want to replace nan with the most common value of the column.

I did this :

`df.iloc[:, - n:] = df.fillna(df.iloc[:, - n:].value_counts().index[0])`

But I have this error :

`TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar or dict, but you passed a "tuple"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because the below code:

```
df.iloc[:,-n:].value_counts().index[0]
```

Returning a `tuple` of values that contains values from all of your columns so you have to specify a particular column from which you want to fill `NaN's` value

here pass the index number of the column:

```
df.iloc[:,-n:].value_counts().index[0]
                              #      ^
                               #column index
```

#For example

```
df.iloc[:,-12:].value_counts().index[0][2]
                          #            ^
 # here I entered column index on the basis of which I want to fill values For the last N columns
```

Finally:

```
df.iloc[:, - n:] = df.iloc[:, - n:].fillna(df.iloc[:, - n:].value_counts().index[0][2])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I have an error : `pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers`
I think it comes from `df.iloc[:, - n:,2]` which contains 3 arguments ?